# Show WooCommerce Products in get_search_query()

Tags: php, wordpress, search, woocommerce

I'm using Divi WP theme and I have the following code in my header:

```
    <form role="search" method="get" class="et-search-form" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">

                <?php

                    printf( '<input type="search" class="et-search-field" placeholder="%1$s" value="%2$s" name="s" title="%3$s" />',

                        esc_attr__( 'Search &hellip;', 'Divi' ),

                        get_search_query(),

                        esc_attr__( 'Search for:', 'Divi' )

                    );

                ?>

                </form>
```

I need to display WooCoomerce products in the search results as well as pages and posts.

I tried adding:

```
                <input type="hidden" value="product" name="post_type" id="post_type" />
```

But in doing so it now only shows WooCommerce products and no longer shows pages/posts.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `pre_get_posts` filter

```
function search_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search) {

            $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'product'));

            $meta_query = array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => '_visibility',
                    'value' => 'visible',
                    'compare' => 'IN'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => '_stock_status',
                    'value' => 'instock',
                    'compare' => '='
                )
            );

            $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

Add this in functions.php of the child-theme, of course you can remove or add any post type in the array defining `post_type` (page, coupon). 
To be sure to retrieve only available products, we need to set a special `meta_query` according to Woocommerce custom fields.

Hope its helps!

Comment: By functions.php, you mean the **theme's functions.php file**.  Also, while I know this answer is correct, you should explain what this does and why it should be used.  Also, your `post_type` should likely *also include* `page` by default, don't you think?

Comment: @cale_b : I added some details as you suggest. I usually don't set pages for search on an e-commerce based site. Menu and links for pages are usually sufficient and not very interresting for search ?

Comment: @Benoti thank you for this but no luck I'm afraid. Adding the code to my functions file in the child theme changes the search results to only showing woocommerce products and no longer shows posts / pages.